# Delete comments with delay

Tags: feature-request, comments

Comments about "deleting comments" with Jon Skeet here (see comments)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1136406/206730

Some comments don't give USEFUL information, I think MHO, I would prefer delete them. 
I prefer Questions in SO with only useful information, not unuseful comments, in MHO.

For example,

"already posted an eg :)",
"I prefer mine :)",
etc

comments written 4 years ago **not useful now**, in MHO.

SO question will be show only useful information, in MHO.

I suggest any link to delete (unuseful) comment with delay, for example, 1 hour, 2 hours, 1 week, 2 weeks, 1 months,6 months, 1 year, etc.

If I click "delete" link now, the comment will be deleted one year after.

Comment: You want to delete Jon Skeet's Comment !!!.....

Comment: I don't think this is really important, but if it were in effect, I wouldn't want the delay to be more than an hour.

Comment: While I agree that the off tangent comment should be cleaned up, I disagree with the mechanism that you suggest.

Comment: Jon Skeet asks you to [stop deleting your comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136399/how-to-update-textbox-on-gui-from-another-thread-in-c-sharp/1136406#comment23165304_1136406) from that post.

Comment: @nhahtdh which better mechanism?.

Comment: It's not clear whether you mean deleting your own comments (which it sounds like within your comments) or deleting the comments of others ("already posted an eg" "I prefer mine")

Comment: @Raynold, the important is useful information in SO questions, in MHO.

Comment: @DavidRobinson deleting my own comments, each user delete own comment itself.

Comment: Give Jon a rest mate. He doesn't need this...

Comment: I have hear community (negative votes). Not suggestion accepted. Delete this post ?

Comment: Just move on... deleting a negatively voted question like this will most likely get you banned from asking questions here. Good luck!

Comment: @JeremyThompson Not deleted better, thanks Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

One problem with having a "Delete my comment in 1 year" button is that other users might respond to your comment at some point during that interim period, at which point the response will seem nonsensical.

Beyond that, I don't think this is really a problem. If you know your comment is off-topic, don't post it, or delete it immediately. If you don't want to delete it immediately (because someone responded to it, for example), then it won't be any better to have it deleted in a year.

Comment: According the comments. For example, "already posted an eg :)",
"I prefer mine :)", not useful one year after, isn't? I think SO question only will be very USEFUL information about the question.

Comment: @Kiquenet: Are you saying that the original posters of those comments should have put in a time-delayed-delete? a) How can you be sure they would have added such a delay at the time? After all, Jon didn't delete his comment even after returning to his answer today. b) What if one of them added a time-delayed delete and the other didn't? One confusing comment (just "I prefer mine" without context, for example) is worse than two relatively harmless comments.

Comment: Maybe SO administrators can be deleted unuseful comments

Comment: @Kiquenet: They already can- you can flag a comment (click the flag icon on the left) to suggest that a moderator delete it.